# Library loading error "ELF file OS ABI invalid" with rocksdb 5.14.2

Tags: java, rocksdb

I can start normally on my mac computer, but it can't be started on my linux server(Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7). `RocksDB.loadLibrary()` throw exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/admin/iotx-lora-server/.default/temp/librocksdbjni6992931247226937799.so: /home/admin/iotx-lora-server/.default/temp/librocksdbjni6992931247226937799.so: ELF file OS ABI invalid
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1971)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:821)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1107)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
```

Comment: It seems that you have incorrect native library on classpath which is not matching your current architecture

Comment: add output of these commands : `file /home/admin/iotx-lora-server/.default/temp/librocksdbjni6992931247226937799.so` and `uname -a`

Comment: @rkosegi `uname -a` command show: `Linux e011239169019.et15sqa 2.6.32-220.23.2.ali927.el5.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 28 14:57:06 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, but `file /home/admin/iotx-lora-server/.default/temp/librocksdbjni6992931247226937799.so` command prompt to “ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), not stripped”